# How should I review an answer not backed up by sources

Tags: discussion

This answer:
[Are Katanas made of steel folded 1000 times?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7878/are-katanas-made-of-steel-folded-1000-times/14839#14839)

which says:

> yes thats correct additives like dust of diamonds or coal and granite and
>
> i can imagine how they knew not to fold it any longer once they started perceiving a nuclear type reaction

Doesn't cite any sources, when reviewing it I wasn't sure what to do with it. Should I recommend deletion, or leave it as it is?

Answer (score 2):

not citing a source is grounds for deletion and should be voted as such, moderators can mark posts with a banner about citations, but most answers that don't cite sources really aren't worth saving, like the one in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it’s deleted now. Thanks for making the effort but you don’t have to post on meta for such posts, just flag them accordingly.

Comment: The reason that I posted to meta is because I wasn't sure it the answer should be deleted, or granted a chance to put its sources.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth mentioning something about the way new users should be introduced to the requirement for references. While I don't want to dilute the requirement, I think there is an issue that some users posting their first questions may be discouraged by the tone in which we ask them to provide references.

For an example see the recently posted answer to this question [Is the climber's head-lamp backstory for this long-exposure photo feasible?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13675/is-the-climbers-head-lamp-backstory-for-this-long-exposure-photo-feasible) .

I sympathize a little with the user https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/13124/sherwood-botsford who provides a reasonably good answer but one lacking references. He argues that the points he is making are "obvious" which I agree with and, I suspect, he feels discouraged at being asked to provide references.

He **should** provide references, but we might want to be "nice" in asking him to do so as the requirements here can take some getting used to. I worry that, sometimes, the language we use is a little offputting for those not used to it and we might want to veer towards offering advice to relatively new contributors rather than comments that say, more or less, "bugger off you didn't provide any references".

PS I don't think the responses to his answer were particularly bad here, but I do think that some encouragement to play by the rules should have been included rather than the bald "please provide some references" statement.